# System.web not have HttpCookie in C#. what's going wrong in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, system.web

when i want to use HttpCookie who a part of System.Web i found that intellisense does not show them nor they found in reference when  i put using System.Web

Can someone show me what thing i need to do to use HttpCookie. i try with using System.Web but still i not see them in intellisense can someone show me how i can use HttpCookie.

i found problem in WPF project their is nothing problem come when i do that in ASP.NET MVC

i can see only three thing  AspNetHostingPermission AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute AspNetHostingPermissionLevel

Comment: Mr. Spielberg, HttpCookie is defined in `System.Web.dll`; do you have that reference included ? And it's quite unusual for a WPF app to be dealing with cookies; can you elaborate on what exactly you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF does have a concept of Cookies, but they are different than what you are use to in Web Applications. What is it you are trying to do?

You can use the `GetCookie` and `SetCookie` on the `Application` class. For an overview of cookies in WPF, you can read here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#Cookies

Comment: I'm pretty sure that will only work in XAML browser applications. I don't think that's what we have here

Comment: Except for that first bullet in the documentation that says "WPF standalone applications and XBAPs can both create and manage cookies."

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference to System.Web in your project.

Right click the project in visual studio, select add reference, and select System.Web from teh list provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project is not Profiled for ".Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile" which is Default. It should be just ".Net 4.0 Framework"

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project is not Profiled for ".Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile" which is Default. It should be just ".Net 4.0 Framework""

It worked for me. At first I had not been able to add ref System.Web, because was have profiled for ".Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile"...